# submit a single form a list of dynamic forms inside html through link

Tags: jquery, html, forms

So i have the following forms from my application:

```
<form action="/admin/Management/removeClass" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="5" />
<a class="sub0" href="#"> Delete </a>

<form action="/admin/Management/removeClass" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="2" />
<a class="sub1" href="#"> Delete </a>

<form action="/admin/Management/removeClass" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="3" />
<a class="sub2" href="#"> Delete </a>
```

the values varies from 1~5,

I want to submit the form through link instead of the usual button and i can do something like this:

```
$('.sub1').click(function(){
$('???').submit();     //how to properly select that form for it?
})
```

What should i add to properly select the right form that should be deleted for post?

Comment: oops that was typo let me fix it.

Comment: that's a placeholder because i don't know what to add to properly select their corresponding form.

Comment: yes i can, if i did how do i submit them? each link corresponds to a different form so.. i am trying to avoid hardcoding them  1 by 1 unless i have no choice.

Comment: ooooo i see, so closest will look for its ancestors and stop at the form?

Comment: hmmm i see alright thank you, im going to try it.

Comment: nvm it works. you can put up an answer then i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.closest()` selector. It will select the first matching element up the DOM.

In your case you want to put:

```
$( '.sub1' ).closest( 'form' ).submit();
```

[Link to jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)